# Which pasuk in megilas esther has all the letters in the aleiph beis

Tags: megillat-esther

Which pasuk in megilas esther  has all the letters in the aleiph beis?

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) LSK and thanks for this first question. Great to have you learn with us!

Comment: @DoubleAA The question you duped this to is about Chumash, not Esther.

Comment: LSK, this question seems to presume that such a pasuk exists in Esther. Is there a reason why you presume that? Including as much information as you have about where the question springs from could make the question stronger. As it is, this post strikes me as a [riddle](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/140/2) - "Can you figure out what I already know and am not telling you?" rather than as a question - "Can you help me learn what I don't know yet?"

Comment: @IsaacMoses The answer has a link to all of tanakh so we could generlize the question if anyone cares. Anyway this is probably closable as a riddle as is.

Comment: Why is this a duplicate?